# Pushbullet importing OS error, circular import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pushbullet

I am having trouble when using Pushbullet in my VS-Code project, it's having a problem with importing pushbullet. I am using Python 3.8.2 on Windows 10, Python 2.7 is also installed, there are two types of error and I have no clue at all

But when I try it manually in python 3.8.2 IDE, it works perfectly. Can someone help me to fix this issue

I have looked through some of the similar post, saying this is the `PATH` problem and try to uninstall `numpy` , I also couldn't uninstall `numpy` because of having no permission problem.

[image: error1][image: erro2]

Comment: One of your problems is that you named your script `pushbullet.py`.  Doing an `import pushbullet` just refers to your script, rather than the actual module of that name.

Comment: oh yea, thanks, totally forgot about the naming.
What about the other error, with test.py as the file name, any idea?